# Convert JSON nested objects

Tags: ios, json, swift3, foursquare, swifty-json

I am getting the following JSON from Foursquare API and I have been struggling with extracting the data:

```
{
  "meta":{
    "code":200,
    "requestId":"58122e59498e5506a1b23580"
  },
  "response":{
    "venues":[
      {
        "id":"4d56c381a747b60cd4a12c2b",
        "name":"Sports Circle",
        "contact":{},
        "location":{
          "lat":31.9,
          "lng":35.9,
          "labeledLatLngs":[
            {
              "label":"display",
              "lat":31.9,
              "lng":35.90
            }
          ],
      ],
      "confident":true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the `name` in `venues` in addition to the `lat` and `lng` values. I have tried this so far but it gets out of the second if statement at `JVenues` because it is `nil`:

```
func parseData (JSONData: Data){
    do {
        var readableJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]

        if let JResponse = readableJson ["response"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
            if let JVenues = JResponse["venues"] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                if let JName = JVenues["name"] as? String{
                    NSLog(JName)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the other answers are getting at.  Will probably make more sense if you can see it all laid out...

```
if let JResponse = readableJson ["response"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
    if let JVenues = JResponse["venues"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
        if let JName = JVenues.first?["name"] as? String {
            NSLog(JName)
        }
    }
}
```

Note this only gets the FIRST name in the array of venues.

EDIT:

I prefer something like this.  Define a struct and convert your dictionaries to the struct:

```
struct Venue {
    var name: String?
    var venueId: String?

    init(_ venueDictionary: [String : AnyObject]) {
        self.name = venueDictionary["name"] as? String
        self.venueId = venueDictionary["id"] as? String
    }
}
```

In your class create a property such as:

```
var venues = [Venue]()
```

From your JSON map the dictionaries to the venue array.  I renamed variables that start with a capital for convention.

```
if let response = readableJson ["response"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
     if let responseVenues = response["venues"] as? [[String : AnyObject]] {
         self.venues = responseVenues.map({ Venue($0)) })
     }
 }
```

Use anywhere in your class like:

```
let venue = self.venues.first
print(venue?.name)
```

Or:

```
if let venue = self.venues.find({ $0.name == "Sports Circle" }) {
    print("found venue with id \(venue.venueId)")
}
```

Comment: thank you for your clarification that worked! 
I am sorry I am new to swift if I want to access the values in name in a variable it is not clear to me how can I do that? is there a link or a tutorial on how to deal with this?

Comment: Added additional help.  If my answer was helpful to you you can up vote it.  Thanks!

Comment: If you need something more permanent, like info you can access throughout the app and on multiple runs, you'll want to learn Core Data.